# How do you test if a multivariate data set is a time dependent series?

Tags: r, time-series, multiple-regression, multivariate-analysis, stationarity

I am running preliminary tests on the two dimension data set. This data set contains 108 data points, and I was wondering whether my data may be considered independent or time-dependent.

I test using multivariate normality test such as `roystonTest`, `mardiaTest`, `hzTest`; they all seem to reject that my data belong to a Multivariate normal distribution.

However, when it comes to fitting a VAR model, I get some coefficients that are significant.

**Question:** I know that doing such tests is not sufficient. I would like to do further test to know whether my data are time-series and dependent or not. How may I do so?

Moreover, is there a way to test if my data follow any of the other well-known distributions such as the mixed multivariate normal model, multivariate t model, multivariate non-central t model, using R?

Comment: You just need calculate the auto correlation and patial auto correlation and plot them, if it's time depends, then the auto correlation coefficient will decrease from higher to lower as the lag increases.

Comment: Thank you very much for this @feng, but is there a way to apply a well-known test other than just plotting and examine the plots. Like is there a test that simplifies this set of tasks?

Comment: you can do the unit root tests

Comment: Thank you very muh for this, But a unit root tests if the data set are not stationary and not if they are not time dependent? I mean that dataset might be time-dependent but not stationary that does not make them independent right?

Comment: There are many threads on CV devoted to addressing questions like these with specification of the many possible tests. You can search for autocorrelation, unit roots, cointegration, HAC errors, stationarity, spurious trend associations, spectral density, fast fourier decomposition, and so on, for ideas.

Comment: Thank you @Djohnson, I understand the test you are mentioning, but all the tests you proposed, more or less, test if the data are stationary or not but they do not test whether the data are time-related or not. That is if the data are stationary then they have nice properties that apply to the same intuition when observations are time independent. But saying that the data are stationary does not imply that they are time dependent because they might be independent (say multivariate normal) but when tested show that they are stationary.

Comment: Is there a way to differentiate between data being stationary or independent (not necessarily normal)?

Comment: I don't agree with your summary. For instance, autocorrelation, heteroscedasticity, stationarity, cointegration, spurious trends and unit roots are distinctly different sources of error and confounding in time series models. In addition, your ability to test and control for each varies with the assumptions and structure of the functional form used, e.g., univariate time series vs panel data models permit more or less solutions. I suggest you drill into each to learn more about their basic properties, enabling you to better differentiate them, before advancing to more sophisticated issues.

Comment: @ DJohnson thank you for this information, but I think you had misunderstood me. I was generating multivariate normal distribution and plotting it corresponding ACF and PACF. I plotted my data's ACF and PACF, and they look pretty similar. However, when I run say a VAR model on each of the observed sample and the generated sample. I get different results. For example, I received that my data have significant lags while that of the multivariate do not.

Comment: I also run normality test on my observed sample, and it seems that I fail to reject (i.e. I accept) that they belong to a normal distribution. Then why am I getting significance in my lagged coefficients when I am fitting a VAR model?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/79187/stationarity-in-multivariate-time-series